# Copy files from FTP server to local directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I want to create a batch file in Windows Server, including the following functions:

- Connection to a FTP server
- Copying the files from there (directory called "out") to a local directory
- if success, then deleting the files from the FTP server
- repeating those steps every 15 minutes

I haven't done that much with batch files so far, so it would be great if you could help me. I know there is the `ftp` command, and I know how to connect (`ftp open`), but unfortunately I don't know how to copy those files from there every 15 minutes.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To program ftp from a batch file, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269. You need to call ftp like this

```
ftp -i -s:ftpcommands.txt
```

where ftpcommands.txt looks something like this:

```
open ftp.myftpsite.com
username
password
bin
cd out
mget *
del *
bye
```

For running this every 15 minutes, see other replies (`at` or Command Scheduler).

(The `-i` parameter is to turn off *interactive prompting* - the other way to do this is to add a `prompt off` command to the commands text file before the `mget`. Without this, `mget` will stop and ask you to confirm before getting each file. [Thanks to Adriano for pointing this out!])

Comment: Ok, I got that. Is there a chance to ensure that all files were copied successfully?

Comment: Aha, I thought you might ask that! I do not think you can do that within the ftp command. You would have to do something like 1) run the ftp command to do the get or mget 2) quit ftp 3) check in the batch file if the files exist (you need to know how many there are...) 4) run ftp again this time just doing the delete.

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer by @AAT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5064408/850848#5064714) suggests using Windows built-in `ftp.exe` command-line client. While that can work, more often it won't, because this client does support FTP active mode only, which does not play nicely with today's ubiquitous firewalls and NATs. It also does not support encrypted FTPS (FTP over TLS/SSL).

If you have a problem with the above, you need to use a 3rd party FTP client. Most of them do support both the passive mode and encryption.

---

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), you can use the following batch file (`.bat`):

```
WinSCP.com /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "get /out/* c:\local\path\" ^
    "exit"
```

In case you already have an `ftp.exe` script, there's a guide for [converting it to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

---

For the scheduling part, see the [guide to scheduling transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

---

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

Windows has the [at](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/at.mspx?mfr=true) utility as well as the Windows [task scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569). Either one can run your program at a specified interval.

Answer (score 0):

Using only one (1) .bat file script. Create the FTP script in a temporary file, run it, then delete the temporary file.

```
SET "FTPFILE=%TEMP%\myftpscript_%RANDOM%.txt"

ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" open ftp.myftpsite.com
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" username
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" password
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" bin
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" cd out
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" mget *
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" del *
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" bye

ftp -i -s:"%FTPFILE%"

IF EXIST "%FTPFILE%" (DEL "%FTPFILE%")

EXIT /B 0
```