# Batch file to Copy files (name_date) from FTP server to local directory?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file, including the following functions:

```
Connection to a FTP server
Copying the files from there to a local directory (just today file named: product_yyyymmdd_hour.csv)
```

I haven't done that much with batch files so far, so it would be great if you could help me. I know there is the ftp command, and I know how to connect at ftp, but unfortunately I don't know how to copy those file. very day I must copy only today file.
for example: Product_20120611_1233.csv
             Product_20120612_1115.csv
             etc.
The source folder an destination folder are the same every day, just the file name is different.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Copy/pasted from [Copy files from FTP server to local directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064408/copy-files-from-ftp-server-to-local-directory)

Comment: Do you ask google? It knows everything! Ex. `ftp batch script`

Comment: yes, but I didn't find a script who copy only this type of files...I couldn't find the comand who can copy only files like product_date_*.csv from ftp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to indicate the today date in batch you have to format it first.
It depends on the date-format you use on your computer.

For example in an Italian format it will be dd/MM/yyyy, in the American one it will be MM/dd/yyyy.

Italian:

```
SET "day=%date:~-10,2%"
SET "month=%date:~-7,2%"
SET "year=%date:~-4%"
SET "dateStamp=%year%%month%%day%"
```

American:

```
SET "day=%date:~-7,2%"
SET "month=%date:~-10,2%"
SET "year=%date:~-4%"
SET "dateStamp=%year%%month%%day%"
```

Once you made this, you can specify the file name in a few ways, E.G.

```
SET "fileName=Product_%dateStamp%_*.csv"
```

Now, you can do a copy in this way:

```
FOR %%f IN (%yourPath%\%fileName%) DO (
    COPY %%f %whereToCopy%
)
```

I don't know how it works in a ftp-script, but you can always change the script you found.