# ftp.exe can't find folders which are environment variable values

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp

I want to use Windows' standard ftp client *(I know that it's bad, but I need it for specific reasons and I got it to work properly)*.

To specify the path where the downloaded file will go, you have to type `lcd [PATH]`.

This worked fine but when I wanted to use environment variables for folders like `%temp%`, it couldn't find them.

Is it just not built into the client, or did I do something wrong?

Logs:

```dos
ftp> lcd %temp%
%temp%: File not found
```

Comment: Build a script file of the ftp commands you want to use and then have `FTP` execute the script file.

Comment: Here is one way to implement @Squashman's suggestion. Use all the variables you want in the `ECHO` statements that write the .ftp file script. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064408/copy-files-from-ftp-server-to-local-directory/47044921?s=1|49.0839#47044921

Answer (score 0):

Environment variable expansion doesn't work just because we want or expect it to. It has to be designed into a program. As [Raymond Chen has pointed out](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120927-00/?p=6483):

> Just because you stick something between percent signs doesn't mean
>   that the magical percent sign fairies are going to swoop in and
>   perform environment variable expansion.

In other words: The `lcd` command in `ftp.exe` would have to be designed to perform environment variable expansion on its command line. It's not designed that way, and this is why you are getting the error message.

One workaround, if you want to change directories using an environment variable, is to use the command `cd %temp%` at the `cmd.exe` prompt (or `Set-Location "$Env:Temp"` in PowerShell) before starting `ftp.exe`.

Another potential workaround noted by commenters on your question is to dynamically create an `ftp.exe` script file.